# How to generate sourcemaps in Bundle Transformer's Less compiler?

Tags: .net, less, source-maps, bundletransformer

I am using the Bundle Transformer to compile Less to CSS on my .NET web project, which seemed like a very fast and easy way to do it.

However I can't find the option to configure the Less compilation to generate CSS sourcemaps. The documentation on the BundleTransformer site is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this thread on the [CodePlex BundleTransformer discussion board](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/discussions/582043) **it is impossible** for various reasons, most notably that BundleTransformer is no longer considered a modern *client-side* build tool and BundleTransformer is recommending you go with Gulp or Grunt - which both have support starting in Visual Studio 2013.3 [according to this Scott Hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx). Thought I'd share as I spent a lot of time researching and looking for this. I'm going to go with Gulp or Grunt.